# Validate inputs using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some `input` fields that I want to validate. For the "email" input I have already done it. For the "Phone" input, I wrote some code that will prevent the user from inserting characters, but it does not work. And for the "Password" input, the user must enter at least 8 characters, including numbers. I need that if user inserts a wrong value, the input borders change to red.

How should I do it? Here is my code in [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/AliMajedHA/2xf6azdj/7/)

The code:

```
app.directive('phoneNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {
        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        console.log(transformedInput);
        if(transformedInput !== text) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  }; 
});
```

Is the code for "Phone" input to prevent the user from inserting characters.

Best Regards

Comment: Use form validations.https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: I already had, but it does not meet my goals, Thanks.

Comment: first add 'novalidate' to disable html5 validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the link of the answer to my question: [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1195760/Validate-forms-using-angularjs#answer1)

with some changes in my [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/AliMajedHA/2xf6azdj/13/)

The code for "PhoneNumber" is:

```
$('#PhoneNumber').bind('keypress', function(e){
       if(e.which != 8) {
         if ((e.which < 48) || (e.which > 57 )) {
           e.preventDefault(); }
        }
      });
```

The `e.which != 8` is for accepting backspace key.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do, on my example, if the user type the char '-' an input error is found ^^

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  if($('input[type="text"]').val().indexOf("-") != -1){
  $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"><br>
```

**Edit:**

This way, you will remove the wrong char

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  if($('input[type="text"]').val().indexOf("-") != -1){
  $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
  $('input[type="text"]').val($('input[type="text"]').val().replace('-',''));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"><br>
```

**Edit:**

This way, you will remove the wrong char from the array of banned chars

```js
bannedChars = ['a','b','c','d'];

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  
  if(bannedChars.indexOf($('input[type="text"]').val().substring($('input[type="text"]').val().length-1)) != -1){
  $(this).css('border-color', 'red');  
  $('input[type="text"]').val($('input[type="text"]').val().substring(0,$('input[type="text"]').val().length-1));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"><br>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want for example, "-" won't being inserted in textbox. Not being inserted but with an alert.

Comment: Done, now this should be ok

Comment: Great! but how should I include all characters except numbers?

Comment: Done, you can put unwanted chars in the array of banned chars

Comment: I think it should be a cleaner code, rather than typing all banned characters in an array, but thank a lot for your helps.

Comment: Yes, you can use regex, it is another technique

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. Please check the following code snippet.

I also tested your phone-number numeric regex, and it works fine. (You can test your regex [here](http://www.regextester.com/30467), or with any other online regex tool.)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    
    $scope.passwordVal = /^[a-zA-Z1-9 ]{8,}$/; // Password Pattern
  });
```

```css
input {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 8px 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
 input.invalid {
   border-color:red !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="myForm" >
   
  Phone: <input type="text" name="my_phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" ng-model="phone" ng-pattern="/^.{11}$/" style="margin:8px 28px;" 
  ng-class="{'invalid': myForm.my_phone.$error.pattern }"  ><br>
  
  Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password"  name="my_password"  ng-class="{'invalid': myForm.my_password.$error.pattern }" ng-model = "password" ng-pattern="{{passwordVal}}">
  </form></div>
```

**OR**

You can do it other way as using the ng-pattern-restrict directive.

Get the library from [here](https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict) and you need to add `ng-pattern-restrict`in input as shown below :

```
 <input type="text" name="my_phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" ng-model="phone" ng-pattern="/^.{11}$/" style="margin:8px 28px;" 
      ng-class="{'invalid': myForm.my_phone.$error.pattern }" ng-pattern-restrict >
```

GitHub: [AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict](https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict)

Comment: Thank, but I want to prevent user from inserting a character, fro example if user inserts "a", it would not being displayed inside input.